# How to copy a database from my laptop into AWS

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services

I have defined a schema and populated with data into MySql on my laptop. However, due to the large-scale of the datasets, the computing time suffers in the following analysis stage in python. So I decide to try to move all my work to cloud. I'm wondering if there is anyway to let the server in AWS directly connect to the mysql server in my laptop so that I can use the existing datasets without recollect them.

Comment: what do you mean by "recollect"? Are you after a local python connection to AWS?

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in [AWS Database Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use DMS database migration service of aws which will do everything for you.

> https://aws.amazon.com/dms/

But you have to take care about foreign key and other data. sometime it is generating the error.

DMS will transfer all of your data from laptop to aws database which will be on RDS or you can choose.